# Export Graph at Different Size and FontSize than Screen

Tags: graphics, export

I like to produce my graphs using `FontSize->12` and `ImageSize->7 57` but I prefer `Export`ing them for publishing at `FontSize->42` and `ImageSize->7 200`. I usually reset the default font and graph size at a cell at the very beginning of the notebook, so I can change and reproduce all the graphs with the new sizes and `Export` them. I bet people here have better ways of doing this. All suggestions welcome.

Comment: That's interesting. I prefer to export at `FontSize -> 10` and `ImageSize -> 227`. (213 is about 8 cm).

Comment: I like to do everything with `FontSize -> Scaled[0.012]` or whatever.